# Closed neighborhood of compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $K'=\{y\in \mathbb{R}:\text{dist}(y,K)\leq d\}$ where $d>0$. I want to prove that $K'$ is closed.

I assumed that it should be quite easy since I solved this kind of problems before but I stucked. Anyway, let me show my attempts.

Let's show that $\mathbb{R}-K'$ is open set. Take $x\in \mathbb{R}-K'$ then $\text{dist}(x,K)>d.$ Let $\beta=\text{dist}(x,K)-d>0$ and my goal to show that the open ball $B(x,\beta)$ does not intersect $K'$, i.e. $B(x,\beta)\cap K'=\varnothing$.

Suppose that $z\in B(x,\beta)\cap K'$ then $|z-x|<\beta$ and $\text{dist}(z,K)\leq d$. Then I am applying triangle inequality in order to get contradiction but I failed.

Could you help me please?

**Remark:** Also I am sure that this is true for any bounded set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, let $z \in B(x, \beta)$ and $y \in K$. Additionally, let $\varepsilon = \beta - |x - z|$. Note that $\varepsilon > 0$. This quantity will come in handy later to give us a bit of a buffer between $z$ and $K'$.

Then by triangle inequality,

$$\text{dist}(x, K) \leq |x - y| \leq |x - z| + |z - y| $$

so

$$\text{dist}(x, K) - |x - z| \leq |z - y|$$
$$\text{dist}(x, K) - \beta + \varepsilon \leq |z - y|$$
$$d + \varepsilon \leq |z - y|$$

Therefore $\text{dist}(z, K) \geq d + \varepsilon > d$, hence $z \notin K'$ as claimed.

Comment: Nice! I was so close :) Thanks a lot for your answer! +1

Comment: These triangle inequality problems always feel kinda tricky to me too because I'm always tempted to start with something like $|x - y| > d$. But it's important to make your inequalities stricter if possible, so use $|x - y| \geq \text{dist}(x, K)$ instead.

Comment: I have a question: You got that $d<|z-y|$ how it follows that $z\notin K'$? This is what I had trouble with

Comment: If $d < |z - y|$ for every $y \in K$, then $\text{dist}(z, K) \geq d$ by definition.

Comment: Oh I see that you could be concerned that maybe $\text{dist}(z, K) = d$...Let me amend my answer

Comment: Sorry I am a bit lost. We have shown that $\text{dist}(z,K)\geq d$. In order to conclude that $z\notin K'$ we need to show $\text{dist}(z,K)>d$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is exactly the same problem which I ran into during the solution

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and $\emptyset\ne A\subseteq X$, the function $d(\bullet,A):X\to\Bbb R$ is Lipschitz continuous because for all $x,y\in X$ and $a\in A$, $$d(y,a)\le d(x,a)+d(x,y)\\ d(y,A)\le d(x,a)+d(x,y)\\ d(y,A)\le d(x,A)+d(x,y)\\ d(y,A)-d(x,A)\le d(x,y)$$

And thus also $d(x,A)-d(y,A)\le d(y,x)=d(x,y)$, which implies $\lvert d(x,A)-d(y,A)\rvert\le d(x,y)$.

Therefore your set is closed.